# Node.js -- Robust HTML parsing + access to javascript functions in HTML

Tags: javascript, parsing, node.js, jsdom

I'm new to node, and looking to extract javascript info from the following example page:

contrived.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            This is a contrived example          
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    var filenames = new Array()
    filenames[filenames.length] = "http://domainwhatever.s3.amazonaws.com/780BONNYVILLECOLDLAKECHRYSLER/4431716.jpg";
    filenames[filenames.length] = "http://domainwhatever.s3.amazonaws.com/780BONNYVILLECOLDLAKECHRYSLER/4431716_1.jpg";
    filenames[filenames.length] = "http://domainwhatever.s3.amazonaws.com/780BONNYVILLECOLDLAKECHRYSLER/4431716_2.jpg";
    filenames[filenames.length] = "http://domainwhatever.s3.amazonaws.com/780BONNYVILLECOLDLAKECHRYSLER/4431716_3.jpg";
    filenames[filenames.length] = "http://domainwhatever.s3.amazonaws.com/780BONNYVILLECOLDLAKECHRYSLER/4431716_4.jpg";

      function pixplosion_Content()
      {
        var eElement = document.getElementById('idLoading');
        if( eElement ) eElement.style.display = 'none';

        return "<pixplosion test=\"test\" flashGasket=\"http://www.realelivepeople.com/pixplosion/assets/flashGasket.swf?contentPath=\" ytBridge=\"/images/image.php?pixplosion=ytbridge\"><tab test=\"test\" label=\"Photos (%1)\" icon=\"Image\" autoIterate=\"false\"   ><tab test=\"test\" label=\"Vehicle Photos (%1)\" icon=\"\" autoIterate=\"true\" startFocused=\"true\"  >
    <image>http://s3.domainwhatever_2.com/vehicles/photos/3726/1300025.jpg</image>
    <image>http://s3.domainwhatever_2.com/vehicles/photos/3726/1300025/35102537.jpg</image>
    <image>http://s3.domainwhatever_2.com/vehicles/photos/3726/1300025/35102538.jpg</image>
    <image>http://s3.domainwhatever_2.com/vehicles/photos/3726/1300025/35102539.jpg</image>
    <image>http://s3.domainwhatever_2.com/vehicles/photos/3726/1300025/35102540.jpg</image>
    <image>http://s3.domainwhatever_2.com/vehicles/photos/3726/1300025/35102541.jpg</image>
    <image>http://s3.domainwhatever_2.com/vehicles/photos/3726/1300025/35102542.jpg</image>
    <image>http://s3.domainwhatever_2.com/vehicles/photos/3726/1300025/35102543.jpg</image><image>http://s3.domainwhatever_2.com/vehicles/photos/3726/1300025/35102544.jpg</image><image>http://s3.domainwhatever_2.com/vehicles/photos/3726/1300025/35102545.jpg</image><image>http://s3.domainwhatever_2.com/vehicles/photos/3726/1300025/35102546.jpg</image></tab></tab></pixplosion>";
      }

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Jsdom chokes on this HTML using its default parser, so I've used aredridel/html5 parser from github.  It seems to work for reading in HTML, through jQuery, but I don't have access to function definitions like I did with jsdom and its default parser.

For example, the following:

```
console.log(window.filenames);
```

With the default parser gives me an array.

With the HTML5 parser, it gives me:

```
undefined
```

Here is my code:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom"),
    fs = require('fs'),
    HTML5 = require('html5');

fs.readFile('contrived.html', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  var document = jsdom.jsdom(data, null, {parser: HTML5});

  // HTML data should be in document creation call
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  // HTML data SHOULD NOT be in window creation call
  var window = document.createWindow();
  var parser = new HTML5.Parser({document: window.document});
  parser.parse(data);

  script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js';
  script.onload = function(window) {
                      console.log('this is a test');
                      console.log(window.filenames);
                      console.log(window.pixplosion_Content);
  }
  document.head.appendChild(script);
});
```

Am I missing something, or is this functionality just not available?

Many thanks.

Comment: It looks like `pixplosion_Content()` returns a multiline string? That doesn't seem right. You need to escape the linebreaks using a `\ `. Also, I don't think the `onload` handler will receive `window`, so by declaring that parameter, you're shadowing your `window` variable. Try `script.onload = function() { ... }` instead?

Comment: Thanks for answering, Linus. The code in 'contrived.html' is not mine, so I am not able to clean it up, at least directly.  As for window, I checked and I can run jQuery functions on window without any problems, I'm just having trouble getting javascript data structures.

Comment: @LinusGThiel: My apologies and my thanks.  You were right about 'window'.  It is still giving the same problem, however.

Comment: Ah, re not your code, I figured as much. Well, that's too bad! Good for you that Aria's html5 parser accepts it. Try putting the onload handler on the document instead?

Comment: +1 for adding this to Elance and SO...